# C# : Remove items from array list when data-source is set,based on condition

Tags: c#

I have an array list for which data-source is set-up during launching the add in from database.Say its List 1 and has these values

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

There is one parent list which has 2 selection "selection 1" & "Selection 2". How can i code so that when i select - "selection" the list should only display

```
AAA
BBB
```

(so that only remove CCC)

(sorry I am new to C# , apology if doesn't sound more clear)

Comment: It would really help clarify your question if you included a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer to show how to create a new collection starting from an ArrayList as was in the OP:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ArrayList aList = new ArrayList() { 1 , 2, 1 };
        IEnumerable<int> result = aList.ToArray().ToList().Cast<int>().Where(v => v != 1).ToList();

        foreach(int item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i remove from ArrayList based on string value?

Comment: [ArrayList.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) would use the equality of the type String to find the item and then if found remove it.

Note: removing this way is linear, **O(n)**, because in theory, every element would need to be tested. Removing this way would only remove the first match.

Comment: so is there a way to remove all matches ?

Comment: @vikashpandey answer updated to show how to do this -- not technically a removal as this is building a new object...

Answer (score 0):

You can use CopyTo (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/3eb2b9x8(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a new list containing only the elements needed and display this one.